# Vertex gradient in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

Is there a way to set a color to each vertex of a polygon and have they blend to form a gradient between them?

A great example of this would be the HSV triangle from [Coolorus](http://www.coolorus.com/) (first image on the right). That triangle has a white vertex, a black one and a yellow one. That cannot be made by hand using linear gradient as far as I know.

Comment: You could do it in Illustrator with a gradient mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this may be to apply multiple Gradient Overlay layer styles to your polygon, each set to Multiply with a different angle. It'll just be a matter of calculating the angles required.

[image]

Here's a triangle with this three-gradient thing applied (very loosely, the angles are very rough). It's by no means perfect, but it might be as close as you're going to get.

Comment: That can't be done. A triangle when divided into 3 don't give 3 rectangles, but three more triangles. Unless there's a triangle gradient that I don't know about, it's not possible. I tried it already, and I do get close, but it's not useful in my case. It needs to be perfect. See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/slHHe.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Close but no cigar.

Comment: Well, I guess I need to write my own program. Thanks anyways.

Comment: or, as @CAI suggests above, use Illustrator